# Using my username and password but login with another account

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm beginner in using yii2 framework. I have an strange problem.

Sometimes after login with **my** username and password in my website, it shows me **another** account and profile, like I use another username for login.

As I said this occurrence happening sometimes **not always**.

What could be related this problem? (controller, session, cookie or ....)

This is class that implements IdentityInterface

```
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface {

    const STATUS_DELETED = 0;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 10;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName() {
        return '{{%user}}';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors() {
        return [
            TimestampBehavior::className(),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules() {
        return [
            ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id) {
        return static::findOne(['id' => $id, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null) {
        throw new NotSupportedException('"findIdentityByAccessToken" is not implemented.');
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByUsername($username) {
        return static::findOne(['username' => $username, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by password reset token
     *
     * @param string $token password reset token
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByPasswordResetToken($token) {
        if (!static::isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)) {
            return null;
        }
        return static::findOne([
                    'password_reset_token' => $token,
                    'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE,
        ]);
    }

    public static function findByType($username) {
        return static::findOne(['username' => $username, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE, 'type' => 'backend']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds out if password reset token is valid
     *
     * @param string $token password reset token
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function isPasswordResetTokenValid($token) {
        if (empty($token)) {
            return false;
        }
        $timestamp = (int) substr($token, strrpos($token, '_') + 1);
        $expire = Yii::$app->params['user.passwordResetTokenExpire'];
        return $timestamp + $expire >= time();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->getPrimaryKey();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAuthKey() {
        return $this->auth_key;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey) {
        return $this->getAuthKey() === $authKey;
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param string $password password to validate
     * @return bool if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password) {
        return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password_hash);
    }

    /**
     * Generates password hash from password and sets it to the model
     *
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function setPassword($password) {
        $this->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
    }

    /**
     * Generates "remember me" authentication key
     */
    public function generateAuthKey() {
        $this->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
    }

    /**
     * Generates new password reset token
     */
    public function generatePasswordResetToken() {
        $this->password_reset_token = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString() . '_' . time();
    }

    /**
     * Removes password reset token
     */
    public function removePasswordResetToken() {
        $this->password_reset_token = null;
    }

}
```

And this is frontend/config/main.php:

```
use \yii\web\Request;

$baseUrl = str_replace('/frontend/web', '', (new Request)->getBaseUrl());
$params = array_merge(
        require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'), require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'), require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'), require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-frontend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',
    'modules' => [
        'message' => [
            'class' => 'frontend\modules\message\message',
        ],
        'gii' => [
            'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
            'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1', '192.168.1.*', 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX'] // adjust this to your needs
        ],
    ],
    'components' => [

        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'enableSession' => true,
            'identityCookie' => [
               'name' => 'frontEndIdentityUser', 
               'path' => '/'
            ]
        ],
        'session' => [
            'name' => 'frontEndIdentity',
            'savePath' => __DIR__ . '/../runtime/sessions',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

Comment: May be you have a collision of more than one user having the same ID. Could you send the code for the class that implements `IdentityInterface` to check?

Comment: @mmonem I added the class

Comment: Does the conflict come from the backend user. I mean when you login but you see another logged in user name, is that strange username is the currently logged in username in the backend app?

Answer (score 0):

If the strange username is the currently logged in username in the back-end app, this can be from session name of the back-end app having the same name as the front-end one.

```
'components' => [
    ...
    'session' => [
        ...
        // name should be different than any other
        // application on the same site
        'name' => 'frontEndIdentity',
        ...
    ],
    ...
]
```

Comment: Could it be, but I think it is separate front-end and back-end sessions.

Comment: @mmonem Could it be, but I think it is separate front-end and back-end sessions.

Comment: You can check that `frontEndIdentity` is not set as the name in the session component of the config of the back-end app

Comment: @mmonem I think this happens when the `enableAutoLogin` is true